# AS400 Enabling SSL to connect via ODBC

Tags: ssl, odbc, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

We have an AS400 mainframe server, where we are trying to connect to it via ISeries or even ODBC via SSL, but it is failing. However the AS400 admin says that it works perfectly via PCOMM, which it does.

I am not an expert at AS400 configuration, but are there additional options while setting up SSL for AS400, that when toggled allows access from other sources besides PCOMM?

Let me know if further information is needed to tackle this.

Comment: We need OS version information to answer this. AS400 hasn't been the name of the platform for a long time. iSeries was the next name in line, and even that is an old name. And AS400 and an iSeries should be able to talk to each other via APPC or APPN. But you are using iSeries in a way that I don't recognize. Maybe you are shortening the name of something like iSeries Navigator or iSeries Access? Maybe you do not have an AS400 but an iSeries, or something newer like System i or Power System?

Comment: Be advised though that systems as recent as v7.1 do not support many of the currently accepted cyphers for SSL, and if you want to do SSL securely you need to be on a recent version of the OS like V7.2 or v7.3.

Comment: ISeries Navigator is being used here. I believe the version used is V7R2.

Comment: You need to use this manual https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzain/rzainpdf.pdf